Magento 2.4.4p4 JWT Access Token not stored in oauth_token table
In magento 2.4.4p4 enterprise edition I noticed when generating access token using the code below
// Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
$customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($username, $password);
// Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory
$token = $this->tokenModelFactory->create();
$token->createCustomerToken($customer->getId());
$accessToken = $token->getToken();

return [[
    'accessToken'=>$accessToken,
    'customer_id'=>$customer->getId()
]];

The accessToken I received value is as below
eyJraWQiOiIxIiwiYWxnIjoiSFMyNTYifQ.eyJ1aWQiOjM1NTk2OSwidXR5cGlkIjozLCJpYXQiOjE3MjMwMjQwMjQsImV4cCI6MTcyMzAyNzYyNH0.QARVztXCFzK6k867g0ulsHPIFOx1GqlWQGKZ4-uBD5M
Which I believe is a JWT Token generated by magento 2.4.4p4 ( JWT because i noticed it has 3 json objects encoded as base-64 strings, concatenated together with full-stop characters, source of reading: https://newbury.me/2022/05/25/jwts-for-api-authentication-in-magento-2/ )
I am actually in the progress of creating a custom login API and custom logout API , but since this JWT Token does not get stored in oauth_token upon the code above is triggered I am not able to retrieve or revoke the token
Appreciate anyone that can help provide guidance how to create custom login and logout function in Magento 2.4.4p4 , I am using the Enterprise version of magento
Attached below is the source code for my login and logout function
<?php

namespace Wowshop\MobileAppApi\Model;

use Wowshop\MobileAppApi\Api\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory;
use Wowshop\ApiSystem\Helper\Data as ApiHelper;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory as OrderCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer as CustomerModel;
use Magento\JwtUserToken\Model\Reader as JwtReader;

class Customer implements CustomerInterface
{
    protected $tokenModelFactory;
    protected $customerAccountManagement;
    protected $resultFactory;
    protected $apiHelper;

    public function __construct(
        TokenFactory $tokenModelFactory,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        ResultFactory $resultFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request,
        ApiHelper $apiHelper,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        OrderCollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory,
        CustomerModel $customerModel,
        JwtReader $jwtReader
    ) {
        $this->tokenModelFactory = $tokenModelFactory;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_apiHelper = $apiHelper;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
        $this->customerModel = $customerModel;
        $this->jwtReader = $jwtReader;
    }

    /**
     * Accept username and password and return token string
     * @author : Farhan
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @return array
     */  
    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $authenticationStatus = $this->_apiHelper->authenticateApiToken($this->request);
        if(!$authenticationStatus['status']){
            return [$authenticationStatus];
        }

        try {
            $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($username, $password);
            $token = $this->tokenModelFactory->create();
            $token->createCustomerToken($customer->getId());
            $accessToken = $token->getToken();

            return [[
                'accessToken'=>$accessToken,
                'customer_id'=>$customer->getId()
            ]];
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            // Handle login failure
            return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle unexpected exceptions
            return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
        }

    }
    /**
     * POST retrieve customer self data
     * @author : Farhan
     *
     * @api
     * @return array
     */  
    public function viewCustomer()
    {
        $customer_id = $this->_apiHelper->getCustomerIdFromToken($this->request);
        if (!$customer_id) {
            throw new \Exception("User not authenticated.");
        }
        
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer_id);
            $address = $this->getCustomerAddresses($customer_id);

            return [[
                'customer_id'=>$customer_id,
                'email'=>$customer->getEmail(),
                'firstname'=>$customer->getFirstname(),
                'lastname'=>$customer->getLastname(),
                'gender'=>$customer->getGender(),
                'address'=>$address
            ]];

        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            // Handle login failure
            return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle unexpected exceptions
            return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
        }

    }

    public function getCustomerAddresses($customerId) {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        $addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
        $addressData = array();

        foreach($addresses as $address){
            $addressData[] = $this->getAddressData($address);
        }

        return $addressData;
    }
  
    private function getAddressData($address) {
        $addressData = [
            'address_id' => $address->getId(),
            'customer_id' => $address->getCustomerId(),
            'firstname' => $address->getFirstname(),
            'lastname' => $address->getLastname(),
            'street' => $address->getStreet(), 
            'city' => $address->getCity(),
            'region' => $address->getRegion()->getRegion(),
            'postcode' => $address->getPostcode(),
            'country_id' => $address->getCountryId(),
            'telephone' => $address->getTelephone()
        ];
        return $addressData;
    }
    /**
     * @author : Farhan
     *
     * @api
     * @return array
     */  
    
    public function logout()
    {   
        $authorizationBearer = $this->request->getHeader('Authorization');
        $authorizationBearerArr = explode(' ', $authorizationBearer);
        $accessToken = $authorizationBearerArr[1];
        // this code able to read acccess token but I am unable to find ways to revoke it as it didnt get stored in oauth_table
        $tokenJwt = $this->jwtReader->read($accessToken)->getUserContext();

        $result = [
            'revoke' => 'fail',
            'delete' => 'fail'
        ];

        try {
            $authorizationBearer = $this->request->getHeader('Authorization');
            $authorizationBearerArr = explode(' ', $authorizationBearer);
            $accessToken = $authorizationBearerArr[1];

            $token = $this->tokenModelFactory->create()->loadByToken($accessToken);
            if (!$token->getToken()) {
                $result['error'] = 'Invalid access token';
            }

            if ($token->getRevoked(true)) {
                $result['error'] = 'Token already revoked';
            }

            if($token->setRevoked(true)->save()){
                $result['revoke'] = 'success';
            }
        
            if($token->delete()){
                $result['delete'] = 'success';
            }

            if ($token->getToken()) {
                $result['error'] = 'Token fail to be deleted';
            }

            return [$result];

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
        }
    }
    
}

